# How to use AWS CodeStar for Angular Applications?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codestar

Can anyone let me know how can we configure AWS CodeStar project for Angular applications?

There is no specific project template exists for angular right now. But i see Node.js + Lambda project template is there.

I don't know how it works since i used to deploy the files under dist/ folder to the server whenever i make some changes.

Is it possible to use CodeStar for angular projects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should definitely be possible, once configured properly. I'm looking into it right now. Have you made any progress since you posted this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Angular CLI. Use the Node.js + Lamda template, and have the build generate the public folder.

Go to your .angular-cli.json file, and modify the apps.outDir to "../public" instead of it being "dist"

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "../public", <-- RIGHT HERE (it tells the build where to compile to)
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
```

],